# how to check the megapixels of a camera on a win 10 tablet?

Tags: windows-10, tablet, camera

I have a win 10 tablet and I want to know the MP(megapixels) of my cameras.
What is the simplest solution? how can I check them? is there any software? or does windows show that?

Answer (score 1):

Take any picture, find the file.
On a desktop/laptop if you just hover over the name with the cursor a pop-up will float, giving you the dimensions.
On a tablet, if you can't do that, then you need to get Properties on the file, then see the Details tab. The dimensions will be shown there.

[image]

Your camera's megapixel count is the first number multiplied by the second, divided by 1,000,000.

The example image would be 1200 x 960 / 1000000 = 1.152megapixels

Comment: the problem is I am unable to take pictures because I don't have a reliable software for taking picture in win 10. Do you know any reliable software for taking pictures with the max possible resolution of camera in win 10?

Comment: Not a clue, sorry. I assumed that if any device had a camera in it, then it would already be set up to be able to use that camera.